# another css 100% height question

Tags: html, css

Sorry but I can't get this to work.  Should be a quick answer.

My html is laid out like so:

```
<html>
    <header> 
    ... 
    </header>

    <body> 
        <div class = "background"></div>
        <div class = "content">
        ...
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

The I want the background div to simply place a 1000px background colour down the entire length of the page.  The content is then padded 40px on each side, inside this background colour.

The css is like so:

```
body {
    width:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.background {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width:1000px;
    height:100%;
}

.content {
    min-height:100%;
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-right:40px;
}
```

I thought it worked like so... The body div would expand to hold the min-height of the .content div.  This means that 100% height of the .background div would fill the entire body and so the length of the page.  However it does not.  It only fills the window height.  Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: quick guess: html, body{height:100%}

Comment: Shouldn't `<header>` be _inside_ `<body>`?

Comment: if only it were that simple! no, even without these, the body and html expand to fill the page length as expected.  however the empty background div refuses to cooperate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As topek guessed, this will do it:

```
html, body{
  height:100%
}
```

The reason this works is because percentage CSS heights only work if the parent element has a height defined on it.  By adding the above, you're giving `.background`'s parents a height.

*Update*: based on OP's comment, here's how you would get the `.background` div to always appear to fill the viewport:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;   
}

/* Fixed element that takes up entire viewport */
.background {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;    

   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; 
}

/* Content that stacks above .background */
.content {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

As `.content` grows larger than the viewport and the user scrolls, the fixed position of `.background` will keep it always in view.

And of course, [a handy example](http://jsfiddle.net/seYCW/).

Comment: the above does not work in my case.  i have of course tried this before posting here.

Comment: any ideas why this doesn't work?  of course defining html and body 100% height is overridden when .content is greater than 100% height anyway.

Comment: cool, simply changing position to fixed does work. html 100% height isn't needed.  seems almost like a hack though... :)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is:

```
body, html {
    height:100%
}
```

Then specify `height:100%`; any DIV you want to have full height.

BTW - 1000px wide is a bad unit to use. People with 1024 wide screens will get horizontal scrollbars. Better to stick to 980 or less. 960 is good because it can be divided by many factors.

Comment: I haven't messed around with css too much recently, so forgive me if I sound a little bit dated, but don't you have to have a defined height?  For example, if an inner div had a height of 250px I could use 100% to stretch something it contained to that height, but if I gave them both heights of 100% it would be the same as letting height be auto?

Comment: giving it a height of 100% gives it the height of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You should put bg into `html` or `body` elements as the first choices.

```
html { background: url("bg.jpg") no-repeat top center; }
```

or

```
body { background: url("bg.jpg") no-repeat top center; }
```

Fixed:

```
background: url("bg.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed; /* And bg will stay in fixed position */
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/GxRcp/

The key in this little example is the `position: fixed;` for `.background` so that it is kept in the screen while scrolling.

If you don't really want to do this and want the background to expand ARROUND the content just make it a normal / relatively positioned element, and wrap it arround `.content`...

If you give a more acurate description of the layout you're trying to create (and maybe why in such a way) we may be able to help you better.

Btw, in your example html there is an error, `header` should be `head`.

Comment: the error is `<header>` should be inside `<body>`, although my browser doesn't mind either way